# what the point of putting pointer after data structure?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am new to C programming, and just learned about structures. My question is what the point of putting pointers after defining a structure? like in this example (this is my senior code btw):

```
struct lecturer { 
    char Lecturer_ID[40];
    char Lecturer_Passport[40];
    char Lecturer_Name[40];
    char Lecturer_Password[40];
    struct lecturer *next; 
} *start, *curr;
```

Comment: that is generally used in order to implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: The point is you are simply declaring two pointers to type `struct lecturer` named `start` and `curr`. You could remove them there (which is a good idea -- you don't need global declarations (presumably) and then later declare `struct lecturer *start, *curr;` in `main()`.

Comment: Whiles Gilless guessed extremely plausibly, why do you not ask the author of that code or read the documentation on it? (I hope "this is my senior code" does not mean you are the author of code you do not understand yourself; not to mention trying to get any kind of degree with it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the topic 'Linked List'.

Imagine you have a unknown number of lecturers which will be given to you at runtime. So you will have to dynamically allocate a space in memory each time a new lecturer record needs to be processed.

In this case you will use the 'next' pointer to create a link between these same type of structured data.

Though, you can find many more detailed(and better) explanations in this site, or youtube etc. Just search for "Linked List"

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted defines both the type `struct lecturer` and 2 variables `start` and `curr` with a type pointer to `struct lecturer`. This could have been written as separate definitions for clarity:

```
struct lecturer { 
    char Lecturer_ID[40];
    char Lecturer_Passport[40];
    char Lecturer_Name[40];
    char Lecturer_Password[40];
    struct lecturer *next; 
};

struct lecturer *start;
struct lecturer *curr;
```

The combined definition is required if the `struct` is untagged and not defined via a `typedef`.